# unit testing python how tos

Tags: python, unit-testing, github

I am new to Github. I am new to writing Unit Test Cases. I have contributed to a project but the owner has asked me to provide unit testcases that fail before the fix and work after the fix. How can I go about doing it? Shall I write them all together? As at one time I will have one copy of the code  (i.e with fix or without fix). I am using Python and importing unittest. I am confused. Before the fix I get an exception so should I use assertRaises() for that. I did read a lot but am not able to start.

Comment: There is no need to use `assertRaises`: The test is *supposed to fail* for the old code, hence a simple `assertEqual` (or one of the other checks) is the right way to go. You only need to use `assertRaises` if you want to test whether a function has correct error handling (e.g. whether it throws the correct exception when invalid input is provided). In general, you *always assert the correct behaviour*.

Comment: Thanks Florian for making me understand the correct usage of assertRaises()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you have a fix for following broken `delta` function:

Broken version:

```
def delta(a, b):
    return a - b
```

Fixed version:

```
def delta(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)
```

Then, provide following testcase. It will fail with the broken version, and work with the fixed version.

```
import unittest

from module_you_fixed import delta

class TestDelta(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_delta(self):
        self.assertEqual(delta(9, 7), 2)
        self.assertEqual(delta(2, 5), 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I assumed the project use standard library unittest module. You should use the framework that the project use.

Comment: Absoultely Perfect Example. Three Cheers. Just one thing: I was thinking of writing two such files one with assertsequal() for the fixed one and one with assertRaises() for the exception(broken one). But I think after seeing your answer I can just go ahead with one file and just having assertsEqual. Now the broken one would fail and then fixed one will pass. Is it acceptable like that or do I need to write 2 files and pass both the tests in fixed one(with assertsEqual) and also pass broken one (using assertRaises)? Anyways +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Dominix, Just assertEqual one.

Comment: When I use assertEqual() and the first test fail, I mean say the call to self.assertEqual(delta(9, 7), 2) than it does not got to execute the next line. How can I make it execute for each test case and print FAIL for all rather than just failing for one and coming out

Comment: You can split test_delta() into test_delta_a_gt_b(), test_delta_b_gt_a().